# Koin, can't find a way to use lazyModule in my app

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin, android-koin

I've seen in the official Koin's [doc](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/modules-android#reducing-startup-time-with-background-module-loading) that is possible to declare a module as lazy to avoid to be pre-allocated on app startup, but I'can't find a way to make it work.

In my gradle config file I have:

```
   api "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
   api "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
   api "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:$koin_version"
```

with koinversion = 3.4.0.
I've also tried to add koin for coroutine dependency but the ide and compiler keep's not finding the *lazyModule* keyword.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Koin's `lazyModule` function is part of the `koin-core-coroutines` module. To use `lazyModule`, you need to add the following dependency to your project's app level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-core-coroutines:<LATEST_VERSION>'
```

You can find the latest version of the koin-core-coroutines module on the [Koin website](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/koin/).